# Using multiple columns with counts in access database designer

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I am trying to display several columns with different counts in a microsoft access query. It doesn't let me do certain things a normal query can b/c it has the sql design view. 
I'd like to display
multiple single etc columns with their counts.

Note: the table names and attributes have been changed.

```
select (select  count(*)as multiple from (select  userId from  dbo.Purchases
 where userId is not null GRoup by userId having count(*)>1) x), (
select  count(*)as single from (select  userId from  dbo.Purchases where
userId is not null GRoup by userId having count(*)=1) x );
```

if I do these separately I can display it, but I'd like to combine them into one query and one row. Is this possible?

```
select  count(*)as multiple from (select  userId from  dbo.Purchases
 where userId is not null GRoup by userId having count(*)>1) x)
```

Comment: *It doesn't let me do certain things a normal query can b/c it has the sql design view*...MS Access GUI has the SQL view for query scripting.

Comment: I ended up using an access form and using a getvalue button to override several inputs using VBA so I could display the counts side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy with 2 queries:

First one, saved as "Purchases Summary"

```
Select UserID, count(UserID) as Count from Purchases Group By UserID
```

With a 2nd built on it:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([count]=1,1)) AS [Single], Sum(IIf([count]>1,1)) AS Multiple FROM [Purchases Summary]
```

I cannot find a clever way to combine this into a single query.

I don't know what my problem last night was, but the single query is

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([count]=1,1)) AS [Single], Sum(IIf([count]>1,1)) AS Multiple
FROM (Select UserID, count(UserID) as Count from Purchases Group By UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don George solution also would work.
I ended up using a form and VBA for each column. An issue I had was that I needed to use a distinct call for unique IDs and when there is a sql design view that's not really supported. *distinctrow* is supported, but it would not work for my query. I ended up writing it as before so that it did not need distinct. 
This is the VBA I used to override each input inside of an access form. The currentDb needs to be connected to the database properly before it will also work.

```
selectStatement = "SELECT Count(* ) FROM (SELECT userID FROM dbo_Purchases WHERE userID is not null  GROUP BY userID HAVING count(*)>1)  AS x;"
rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(selectStatement).Fields(0).Value
[Text30].Value = rs
```